# How can I add a new row in a separate database when someone registers via Wordpress?

Tags: php, login, mysql, wpdb, sql

Apologies if this is question is too general or in the wrong location but I am new to SQL, Wordpress and web hosting.

So I am a game developer using Unity C# to create a multiplayer game. I am using GoDaddy web hosting, with WordPress for a company website. The goal is to allow users to create WordPress user accounts via the website or in game. When a user is successfully registered on the wp_users database I would like a new row added to a separate database which will contain the user's in game data (such as games played, won, lost, avatar appearance etc). Upon adding the new row, I would like int fields in the databases filled linking them together by the id indexes. So wp_users has an int column which links to the primary key of the game data database and vice versa. Both databases are currently setup. How would I go about appending the WordPress register code to add in the additional data? Is this the correct way or is there a more traditional way to achieve this that I am missing due to inexperience?

I am more than willing to learn the php/sql code to get this to work but I feel I need pointing in the right direction as currently I am feeling a bit overwhelmed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(As you said, this is not specifically a Wordpress question except for how to hook into Wordpress functionality with users. Here are some thoughts)

I think there are some design questions you need to have clear in order to make it easy figuring out the order to build things:

1. Users signing up and signing in to your Wordpress website is easy, Wordpress does that. But how are you going to facilitate users signing up in an external application? Maybe you need to have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/ to make sure you're clear on how that could happen.
2. It sounds like Wordpress is about to become the authoritative database for your user records. I.e. for the User ID in your game database to be valid, there must be a row in the Wordpress users tables. This is something to be aware of because it means your other application's data will be dependent on Wordpress's database. This is fine and probably not a bad design given that I'm assuming you need Wordpress features for your website.
3. I'd strongly recommend you try and keep the application code for your game separate from Wordpress as much as possible. That means put it in separate PHP files as much as possible. The more you mix in Wordpress PHP with your application PHP the harder your life will be in building features that are specific to your game. You can achieve this by writing all the code for your game in separate files then making the 'glue' that connects Wordpress to your game as small as possible. This also means you can build and test a function to e.g. add a user with ID 123 and score 456 to your game database completely separately, then figure out how to add it to Wordpress once it's done.
4. If you solve item 1, then you could use e.g. the `user_register` hook (see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/)) to do stuff when a new user is registered, and the hook will send you the new user ID so you automatically have that in order to make the new row in your other database.

These are just some ideas to start you off, I would recommend that you try to break your question up into smaller pieces if you're looking for more specific answers.

HTH